# How do I create a Reactor Netty HttpClient without SSL

Tags: java, ssl, reactor-netty

I am creating an HttpClient to send a simple string to a server that I am currently mocking with mockserver-netty.

```
HttpClient.create(opts -> opts.connect(port));
```

and

```
public void send(HttpClient client) {
    this.log.error("sendHttptMessage");
    client.newHandler((in, out) -> out.send(Flux.just(getTestRequest()).map(s -> {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            return out.alloc().buffer().writeBytes(s.getBytes());
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw Exceptions.propagate(ioe);
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())).then(in.receive().asByteArray().map(bb -> {
        this.log.debug(new String(bb));
        return new String(bb);
    }).then())).block(Duration.ofSeconds(15)).onClose().block(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
}
```

where getTestRequest() returns the String I build for the test.

However it appears that I have to setup a whole SSL environment with errors:

Unable to load the library 'netty-tcnative', trying next name, etc

ReactiveException: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out

Is there a way that I can use the HttpClient from reactor netty without setting up SSL?

Thanks